# Updating Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server using Alembic

Tags: postgresql, azure, alembic

I'm looking to amend some tables I have in a PostgreSQL instance on Azure, but I cannot work out how to perform the upgrades with Alembic.

I have been following the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sOvCWFmrtA&t=10287s), which includes a Heroku deployment around the 12:01:00 mark. In that case, once the changes have been defined, we can run `heroku run "alembic upgrade head"` to perform the upgrade. However, I cannot find the equivelant process for Azure.

My postgres instance is housed in a VNet and connected to a web app. Until now, I've made code changes to a server which is running in an attached web app. I push to GitHub which then deploys the changes in Azure. Obviously, if the table already exists in postgres, changes I make to the original schema are not reflected. I considered deleting the table and stating again, but this seems a very risky strategy.

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73448843/how-can-i-run-a-alembic-upgrade-in-azure-postgres), but has remained unanswered. I've also checked the documentation for [Alembic](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/) and [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-postgresql-azure-postgresql-online) but could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was:

- Including Alembic in my virtual environment (`requirements.txt` file)
- Ensuring the `alembic.ini` file is at the root of my project which gets deployed via GitHub to Azure
- Updating `alembic/env.py` to parse the Azure environment set `AZURE_POSTGRESQL_CONNECTIONSTRING` to set the appropriate connection values for Alembic using:

```
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', <connection_string>)
```

- Add a [Startup Command  to you Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#customize-startup-command) to invoke the Alembic upgrade and start the web server. What I used:

```
alembic upgrade head; gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 application:app
```